# Questions about a finite solvable group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

These questions  are by Moshe Newman

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group of derived length $d$, with the
property that every proper subgroup and every proper quotient of $G$ has
derived length less than $d$.

> 1) Can one give an upper bound on the number of different prime
>   divisors of $|G|$, the order of $G$, a bound that depends only on $d$?
>
> 2) Can one give an upper bound on the number of elements required to
>   generate $G$, a bound that depends only on $d$?

For $d=2$ the answer to both questions is yes, and the bound is $2$ in
both questions. (See Miller and Moreno, for example.) What happens in
general?
Comment : one cannot bound the composition length, even for the case d
= 2. Thus one can only hope to bound the number of distinct prime
divisors of $|G|$, and not the total number of prime divisors counting
multiplicity.
Comment : assuming the answer to 2) is yes, it is the case that the
bound must grow with $d$. Is this true for 1) as well?

Comment: I think you can construct examples for a given $d$ that are divisible by $d$ distinct primes, so the answer to the very final question  is yes. Construct a sequence of groups $S_1,S_2,\ldots$ with $S_1 = C_2$, where each $S_k$ is divisible by the first $k$  primes. For $k>1$, let $S_k$ be the semidirect product of a faithful irreducible ${\mathbb F}_{p_k}S_{k-1}$-module with $S_{k-1}$, where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime. Since each $S_k$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup, such a module always exists.

Answer (score 2):

This partial solution by Stuart Margolis:

The answer to question $2$ is definitely yes, the number of elements
required to generate $G$ can't be more than $D=2^{d-1}$. Suppose that $G$
requires more than $D$ generators, then every $D$-tuple of elements of $G$
must belong to a proper subgroup, which therefor must be solvable of
derived length at most $d-1$. So every $D$-tuple of elements satisfies the
identity (in $D$ variables) that defines being solvable of derived
length at most $d-1$. So $G$ itself must be solvable of derived length at
most $d-1$.

This is just a special example of the fact that if a variety (in the
Hanna Neumann sense) is defined by an $n$-variable law then: a group
which is not in the variety, but all its subgroups do belong to the
variety, must be generated by at most $n$ elements.